# How to override scrollbar autohide

Tags: css, scrollbar

Chrome and Safari tend to autohide scrollbars and on macOS, it is pretty aggressive. There's a page on our website that has multiple sections and one of them has a scrollbar which needs to be visible at all times. Currently, it is only visible when the user actually scrolls or is actively on the specific `div`.

**I am looking for a way to force the browser to show the vertical scrollbar at all times.**

<sub>*There are a lot of solutions to this here and elsewhere but most of them don't work as they are outdated. I couldn't find any solutions that work consistently so, in case there's an answer that works somewhere on this site, feel free to mark this as duplicate.</sub>

Comment: Please provide the sample code so that I can get the clear idea what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi, please check [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) I know it's a latest article and you might find it helpful. Also the element which you have scroll make sure that has overflowY as auto or scroll

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, try this:

```css
html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/)